# Bytes from unpredictable data in Python

Tags: python, arrays

We receive data from an API call and we can't predict the nature of that data. The challenge is just to code a bullet-proof conversion (which I naively thought would be very easy) resulting in an iterable bunch of bytes (bytearray or bytes). I've tried a variety of approaches, even trying io.BytesIO, but some input types still get rejected (a code type kicks out, for example). Any suggestions? It shouldn't be this hard just to treat data as bytes. Thanks for any help.

```python
    def process_binary_object(self, api_data):
        api_dat_size = sys.getsizeof(api_data)
        if api_dat_size < 4 or api_dat_size > 4096:    # somewhat arbitrary
            return '0123'
        if isinstance(api_data, bytes):
            self.binary_seq = api_data
            print("Conversion technique aa succeeded.")
        else:
            try:
                self.binary_seq = api_data.tobytes()
                print("Conversion technique bb succeeded.")
            except (AttributeError, TypeError):
                try:
                    self.binary_seq = bytearray(api_data)
                    print("Conversion technique cc succeeded.")
                except (AttributeError, TypeError):
                    try:
                        mem_view = memoryview(api_data)
                        self.binary_seq = mem_view.tobytes()
                        print("Conversion technique dd succeeded.")
                    except (AttributeError, TypeError):
                        self.binary_seq = io.BytesIO(api_data)
                        print("Conversion technique ee succeeded.")
        # some types still don't make it
        first_four = self.binary_seq[:4]
        return first_four
```

Answer (score 1):

After time and working with Java and reading a code book I came across this for the strategy of handling bytes.

Bytes were originally interpreted by the Java Virtual Machine.  If your source of bytecode is from java implemented web services, then launch a JVM and configure the stream for the JVM to parse and the JVM will do the rest in this on demand basis in real time.

This is done by attaching an JIT(Just in Time) compiler to your JVM and the bytecode will compile into executable native code in real time.  Any other bytes that are not code will be interpreted as such.

Biography:  Java Seventh Edition, The Complete Reference

Answer (score 0):

You could regular expression the common word byte for your true/continue case

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear. The input is not always one consistent type, it changes, and I need a reliable way to always have iterable bytes. But thank you for your help in any case. I hate to admit it, but I think I'll be forced to write the data to a file and read it back in as bytes, putting a huge, embarrassing delay into the process. Depressing.

Comment: Thats what the built in command 'type' is for.  It will identify the type for you.  Try type(api_data)  If type(api_data) == str:  do something  ....if python cant identify the object, you will need to setup your environment with the api_libraries that is sending the data in

Comment: Say I identify the 15 or 20 types we've received over the past several weeks. 
Some types use an obj.tobytes() function, so I could hard-code that for those types. Some types need obj.to_bytes(), so I could hard-code that for those types. Some types only have obj.to_bytearray(), so I could hard-code that for those types. Some types only have a obj.to_byte_array(), so I could hard-code that for those types. Now we go into production and then a week later we get a new type that needs obj.convert_to_bytes(), but we didn't code for that type, so our process blows up. That is the issue.

Comment: escalate up, get someone on the phone, create a standard template for your interface and distribute it, make it their responsibility to provide the converter.  Have a meeting with all your providers as a team, and get everyone to understand and on the same page

Comment: I could have dozens of meetings, have dozens of escalations and get dozens of people on the phone. The answer would be, "You are responsible to convert the data into bytes, no matter what comes in. That is your job. Why is that so hard? If Python can't do it, throw it out and get a better language. Don't invent a new requirement and try to force it on us. We told you the input could have any possible layout and it was never our responsibility to conform to any particular format." Everyone is on the same page.

Comment: It is so hard because there is no standard requirement for the objects and all the risk falls on our company because you agreed to some requirement that you do not understand, and I have two balls, but their not made of crystal, so I can't predict the future to know what kind of objects will be sent to me without some kind of standard being followed...and when you force a technical solution to me, you are tying my hands to innovate and create real solutions to problems, while you sit back and pretend like you know what your doing because you know what bytes are.

Comment: Bytes are bytes, they're just a series of bits, most programming languages can handle that. If the data fails the conversions I showed in the code, I'll write it out to a file and then read it back in, solving the immediate problem. Longer term, I'll recommend we use a different language that can handle a simple, trivial task like this without resorting to such an onerous, inefficient kludge.

Comment: Sorry monitors, I wasn't aware that long discussions are frowned upon. I'm also sorry that my comments began to slip into being snarky. To CH: I sincerely appreciate that you took time to help. Thank you for your suggestions.  ~~end~~

Comment: Sorry there's no shortcut answer.  I would create a class, store the api locally, and write a series of functions to inspect it...and document what you want as you go using @precondition and explain what you're looking for.  Just writing that down will clarify your intentions and give you new ideas.  When it gets too complex, write another subfunction that simplifys the problem and repeat piece by piece until there is a solution.  I'm having success with this method.  Slow, yes, but you will understand it and be able to explain it later.